# Use number as key in GraphQL Schema?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Can you use numbers as a key in GraphQL Schema using the GraphQL Schema Language? i.e. (this is a small snippet...)

```
type tax_code_allocation_country_KOR_states {
  "11": tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  "26": tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  "27": tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
}
```

OR the below, which I realise is incorrect JSON:

```
type tax_code_allocation_country_KOR_states {
  11: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  26: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  27: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is forbidden by the [specification](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Names). It is possible to prefix the numbers with an underscore:

```
type tax_code_allocation_country_KOR_states {
  _11: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  _26: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  _27: tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
}
```

Or alternatively not do this on the type level at all and instead map the query or simply run a filter query:

```
type tax_code_allocation_country_KOR_states {
  tax(code: 11): tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query
  tax(codes: [11, 26, 27]): [tax_code_allocation_state_tax_query]
}

# query subselection
{ _11: tax(code: 11), _26: tax(code: 26), _27: tax(code: 27) }
```